# How to include an Excel range in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dataframe

I've been trying to write an algorithm that would help me answer emails more efficiently, and I hit an impasse when I got to the formatting of the response.

So, the response is a pre-structured text and I want to embed an Excel range in the middle of it as a table, to then copy it to the clipboard and paste it, then send it. Basically, the reply should look as follows:

- "The data you requested is:"
- Table
- "Thank you for contacting us"

I've tried using Pandas.Dataframe.to_string() for that purpose, but the formatting is very disorganized and unpleasant to look at. I know how you can copy an Excel range to an email and it works well, so I was wondering if there's any way one can embed an Excel range to a string, to then copy it to the clipboard.

Here's a snippet of code related to the response setup:

`response_string = response_string + response_template[:243] + df.to_string(index=False) + "\n\n" + response_template[243:]`

Maybe I'm doing something wrong by using a regular string variable for the response?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#basics) templates for that.

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

def render_email(df):
    env = Environment(
        loader=PackageLoader("app"),  # Choose another loader if convenient
        autoescape=select_autoescape()
    )
    template = env.get_template("template.html")
    return template.render(dataframe=df)
```

Being your template file `template.html`:

```
The data you requested is:
{% for key, value in dataframe.iterrows() %}
{{key}}: {{value}} {# You can choose here how to iterate/display your data #}
{% endfor %}
Thank you for contacting us
```

How you iterate your dataframe depends on the data it contains.

Comment: So, I've tried the answer and it seems satisfactory, but there's a small obstacle I can't find an answer to online. So, in my company we use Outlook and when composing an email you can use some "HTML mode" to embed images and tables to it. I'm wondering how to copy and paste the HTML from the Jinja template to Outlook and have it look like text, rather than HTML code. Do you by chance have any idea on how to work that out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set any file type as a jinja template. The same template named "template.txt" will render the same content. If your template does not contain any html tag, then it wont be html at all.